# Keyboard keys EXCEPT for F and media keys do not work after waking up from hibernation

Tags: usb, keyboard, hibernate

I have recently got an upgrade:

- MoBo: Gigabyte Z690 UD DDR4 rev1
- RAM: 32GB Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro SL
- CPU: 13600k

Keyboard is Logitech Multimedia Keyboard 600.

The problem is that about 60% of the time when the PC wakes up from hibernation, the mouse is working, even the keyboard's F and media keys and knobs are working but none of the normal keys do. I initially realise this as I notice the numlock light being off.

**Prior to the upgrade, this never happened. Same SSD/OS installation.**

The only fix is a system restart. Replugging doesn't work. Same with all other USB ports, 2.0 or 3.0.

**Already tried the following:**

- Enabled Allow this device to wake the computer both for the keyboard as well as the Root Hub / Disabled (was already the case) allowing the PC to shut down the device to save power.
- Driver update/complete reinstall
- Remove and readd on Device Manager
- Tinkering with all of  the USB options on the BIOS one by one
- Tinkering with all of the power management options
- Tinkering with Group policy settings related to USB ports and power management

I have no clue what to do at this point and it is very irritating having to restart the PC each time this happens. And it happens quite often, especially if the hibernation was that of a longer one.

Appreciate any help/insight!